# How to remove I/O warning failed to load external entity

Tags: php, xml

I'm aware what this warning means and I'm trying to prepare for an instance when the xml file does not in fact exist and cannot be loaded. This script is called from a list of links using the GET method to select the specific XML files.  But I can't figure out how to get rid of this warning when the XML file doesn't exist. Any help would be appreciated

```
if (isset($_GET['reader'])) {
$orders = simplexml_load_file($_GET['reader'],"SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOERROR |  LIBXML_ERR_NONE) or die("Error: Cannot create object"); 

//code

}else{
            echo "Invalid request!";
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the file exists:

```
if (isset($_GET['reader']) && file_exists($_GET['reader']))
```